# split function in xts

Tags: r, time-series, finance, xts

I don't understand why split applied to xts gives a list of lists. It should return xts objects. Is there something I am missing?

```
data(sample_matrix)
x <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
spl<-split(x, f="days")
class(spl)
 [1] "list"
class(spl[1])
 [1] "list"
class(x)
 [1] "xts" "zoo"
```

Edit: I want to rebuild the xts, with a new field I calculated after splitting it into days. The problem is that now my calculations are in the "split" format, that is in a list of list. How can I "rebuild" a xts from the list of list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
> class(spl[[1]])
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

`split(x, 'days')` creates a list of `xts` objects.  The `[[` operator is used for extracting elements from a list.

Edit to address your edit:

```
do.call(rbind, spl)
```

(if that doesn't make sense, then provide a reproducible example)

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Many Thanks. Just to know: do.call essentially is a loop?is it optimized?

Comment: do.call has a help page. Type `?do.call`.  it takes a function as its first argument and a list of arguments for that function.  So, with this example, it's like calling rbind(spl[[1]], spl[[2]], spl[[3]], ...)

Comment: @Mitch76: If I have answered your question, please "accept" it. Thanks.